# Google Drive API: How to update Parents property of File in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am attempting to copy a file from one folder to another using the C# google drive API.

Unfortunately, there is no documentation (that I can find) for doing this in C#: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/folder

Here are a few ways I've tried:

```
Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File file = _files.Where(x => x.Name == fileName).First();

_driveService.Files.Update(file, file.Id).AddParents = _destinationFolderId;

_driveService.Files.Update(file, file.Id).Execute();
```

```
Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File file = _files.Where(x => x.Name == fileName).First();

file.Parents = new List<string> { _destinationFolderId  };

_driveService.Files.Update(file, file.Id).Execute();
```

```
Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File file = _files.Where(x => x.Name == fileName).First();

_driveService.Files.Update(file, file.Id).Fields = "addParents";

_driveService.Files.Update(file, file.Id).Execute();
```

However, all of these throw an error:

*The service drive has thrown an exception. HttpStatusCode is Forbidden. The parents field is not directly writable in update requests. Use the addParents and removeParents parameters instead.*

There are no **addParents** or **removeParents** parameters that I can see, like there are in the python API:

```
file = drive_service.files().update(fileId=file_id,
                                    addParents=folder_id,
                                    removeParents=previous_parents,
                                    fields='id, parents').execute()
```

Perhaps the error message is misleading / incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update method follows the patch methodology. This means that you only send what you want to update and not the other fields.

Updating parents however is a little different it requires the user of the AddParents and RemoveParents methods.  If you dont actually want to change any of the other metadata in the file then you can just send a null value for the file body.

```
var updateRequest = service.Files.Update(null, fileId);
updateRequest.AddParents = folderId;
updateRequest.Execute();
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. I think I actually read a helpful article you wrote about the Google Drive API. Anyway, I am still getting the same error when using the suggested code in your answer.

Comment: Try the update if that doesn't work I will build a sample for it over lunch.

Comment: @DalmTo I tried using the `AddParents` method on the request object, but `AddParents`  appears to be a getter / setter property. I tried anyway, and I get a different, although similar error: `The service drive has thrown an exception. HttpStatusCode is Forbidden. The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable`

Comment: you are including to many fields. in the metadata still.  Just add id nothing else.

Comment: @DalmTo here is the exact code that is throwing the error. The request.Execute is what throws:

<pre><code>
var fileMetadata = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File()
            {
                Id = fileId
            };

            var request = _driveService.Files.Update(fileMetadata, fileMetadata.Id);

            request.AddParents = "1BnhmtN_2hXLLgRbY*************";

            var result = request.Execute();
</code></pre>

Comment: Sorry it took so long i got busy today. Hers a working example.